# Expanding a matrix diagonally with Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `B` and I want to obtain a matrix `C` of dimension `(L+k)*m` by `L*n`. `L` and `k` are input values. `B0 , B1 , ... , Bk` has size `m` by `n`.

[image]

For example :

If I have a matrix `B = [1 1 ; 1 1 ; 1 1]` with `B0 = [1 1]`, `B1 = [1 1]` and `B2 = [1 1]`, and each `B0 , B1 , B2` of dimension `1` by `2` with `k = 2` and `L = 4`.

Then the matrix `C` obtained is given by `C = [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ; 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ; 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 ; 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 ; 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ; 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]` and of dimension
`6` by `8`.

[image]

I would like to generalize my program for any size matrix `B`.

My program solves the problem for `B = [1 1 ; 1 1 ; 1 1]` with `m = 1` , `n = 2` , `k = 2` and `L = 4`.

My code :

```
clc;
clear;

k = 2;                    
L = 4;                   

B = [1 1 ; 1 1 ; 1 1];    
B0 = [1 1];
B1 = [1 1];
B2 = [1 1];
m = size(B0,1);
n = size(B0,2);

c = [B ; zeros(size(B))];
C = zeros((L+k)*m,L*n);

for i = 1:L
    
    C(:,2*i-1:2*i) = circshift(c,i-1,1);
    
end
```

Result : `C =`

```
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

I have difficulties to generalize for any given matrix `B` and for any value of `k` and `L`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
B = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 100 110 120; 130 140 150; 160 170 180];  % input
L = 4;                                                             % input
k = 2;                                                             % input
m = size(B,1)/(k+1);              % obtain m
n = size(B,2);                    % obtain n
C = zeros((L-1)*m+1, (L-1)*n+1);  % initiallize result
C(1:((L-1)*m+1)*n+m:end) = 1;     % each 1 marks the upper-left corner for a copy of B
C = conv2(C, B);                  % insert copies of B, extending size
```

The second-to-last line uses [linear indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-2). The last line applies [two-dimensional convolution](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html). The result in this example is

```
B =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
   100   110   120
   130   140   150
   160   170   180

C =
     1     2     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     4     5     6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     7     8     9     1     2     3     0     0     0     0     0     0
   100   110   120     4     5     6     0     0     0     0     0     0
   130   140   150     7     8     9     1     2     3     0     0     0
   160   170   180   100   110   120     4     5     6     0     0     0
     0     0     0   130   140   150     7     8     9     1     2     3
     0     0     0   160   170   180   100   110   120     4     5     6
     0     0     0     0     0     0   130   140   150     7     8     9
     0     0     0     0     0     0   160   170   180   100   110   120
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   130   140   150
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   160   170   180
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you @Luis Mendo.

Comment: Hi Luis, I've suggested a small modification to take into account the case where `size(B,1)/(k+1)` do not output an integer. You can eventually add this option in your answer so I could delete my proposition.

Comment: @obchardon Nah, I think it's best to keep your answer. Besides, it uses a different approach (`sparse`) to create the 0-1 matrix

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @LuisMendo's answer:

If `size(B,1)/(k+1)` do not produce an integer, then his solution can fail.

I would suggest to create the `C` matrix with `sparse()`:

```
n = size(B,2)
C = full(sparse(1:k:k*L,1:n:n*L,1))
```

So the whole code become:

```
B = ones(7,3);                       % An input matrix that will produce an error with the linear indexing solution. 
L = 6;                               % number of repetition
k = 2;                               % row-shift
n = size(B,2);                       % obtain n
C = full(sparse(1:k:k*L,1:n:n*L,1)); % Create C using full(sparse())
C = conv2(C, B)                      % insert copies of B, extending size
```

(all credits goes to LuisMendo for the idea)

Answer (score 3):

This solution as @obchardon's answer uses `sparse` but unlike the @LuisMendo's answer doesn't use `conv2`. Indices of blocks are computed and used in `sparse` to form the desired matrix.

```
    [row col] = find(true(size(B)));
    ROW = row + (0:L-1)*k;
    COL = col + (0:L-1)*size(B,2);
    C = sparse (ROW, COL, repmat (B, 1, L));
```

Comment: Simplest solution! Very nice