# MATLAB : How to construct block bi-diagonal matrix from input arguments

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have two binary matrices `A0` and `A1` and I would like to create a bi-diagonal matrix `A` defined as follows (`L` being an integer factor):
[image]

**Example**: Let `A0` and `A1` be two matrices and `L` an integer:

[image]

The code proposed by Luis Mendo on [How to unfold a Matrix on Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65049810/how-to-unfold-a-matrix-on-), for the diagonal case is :

```
A0 = [1 0 ; 1 1];
A1 = [0 1 ; 1 0];
L = 2;
A2 = [A0 ; A1]; 
A3 = repmat({A2}, L, 1);
A = blkdiag(A3{:});
```

- Result for `L = 2` : `A =`

  ```
  1     0     0     0
  1     1     0     0
  0     1     0     0
  1     0     0     0
  0     0     1     0
  0     0     1     1
  0     0     0     1
  0     0     1     0
  ```

According to my explanation I had to find: `A =`

```
  1     0     0     0
  1     1     0     0
  0     1     1     0
  1     0     1     1 
  0     0     0     1
  0     0     1     0
```

- For `L = 3` with this code we get :`A =`

  ```
  1     0     0     0     0     0
  1     1     0     0     0     0
  0     1     0     0     0     0
  1     0     0     0     0     0
  0     0     1     0     0     0
  0     0     1     1     0     0  
  0     0     0     1     0     0
  0     0     1     0     0     0
  0     0     0     0     1     0
  0     0     0     0     1     1
  0     0     0     0     0     1
  0     0     0     0     1     0
  ```

According to my explanation I had to find: `A =`

```
 1     0     0     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0     0
 0     1     1     0     0     0
 1     0     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     0     1     1
 0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     1     0
```

How can I construct this matrix?

Comment: This looks to be the result which is asked for, apart from that you have entered 2x3 matrices for `A0` and `A1`, rather than the 2x2 ones you show in your image. The matrices, though, are on the correct locations in the big `A` matrix. Just enter the desired 2x2 matrices. Oh, and you might want to attribute the code to [this answer by Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65049991/5211833) on your previous question for completeness and politeness.

Comment: Thank you @Andriaan, I just corrected. But it is not the same procedure of generation of the matrix A.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expanding a matrix diagonally with Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795599/expanding-a-matrix-diagonally-with-matlab)

Comment: No @obchardon, that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @m2016b and ... can we know why it does not answer the question ?

Comment: By choosing A0 = [1 0 ; 1 1] and A1 = [0 1 ; 1 0] and for L = 3 for example the dimension of the matrix A in this case is : 12*6. Whereas in the procedure that I have explained I obtain a matrix A of dimension 8*6. 

- What I look for as a result: A = [A0, zeros(2,2), zeros(2,2) ; A1,A0,zeros(2,2); zeros(2,2),A1,A0 ; zeros(2,2), zeros(2,2),A1].

- Result with the above code: A = [[A0;A1],zeros(4,2),zeros(4,2) ; zeros(4,2), [A0;A1], zeros(4,2) ; zeros(4,2), zeros(4,2),[A0;A1]]. Thanks.

Comment: But the solutions suggested in [Expanding a matrix diagonally with Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795599/expanding-a-matrix-diagonally-with-matlab) are totally able to treat this case, if you set `K=2` and `L=3`... again there is no difference.

Comment: Using the accepted answer in the link posted by @obchardon with `L=3` and `k=1`, I get an 8x6 matrix with the same values as your desired matrix.

Comment: You are absolutely right. By taking for example the accepted solution in the link posted by @obchardon and setting k to 1 and varying L, I get exactly my answers. Thank you all very much.